# Brute Force numeric attack on any file

Tags: python, pdf, passwords, brute-force

I wrote this brute force attacker in Python. It cracks any file numeric password protected file.

```
import pikepdf

def brute_num_attack(file):
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            print(i)
            with pikepdf.open(file, password=str(i)) as file:
                print("Password: ", i)
                print("Total pages:", len(file.pages))
                break
        except:
            i += 1
```

If I need this to do a brute force attack of all alphanumeric characters and punctuation, how should I do it?

Using this:

```
characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
```

This is just for proof of concept how brute force is implemented.

Comment: Are you aware that that string contains 94 characters and you will have to try 689,869,781,056 passwords for a password length of 6 (94^6)?

Comment: Yup. This is just for practice and proof of concept.
I tried using for loops but did not get desired functionality.